# synchronous messaging with STOMP over HornetQ

Tags: java, jms, synchronous, hornetq, stomp

I am trying to figure out how to do syncronous messaging using stomp with hornetq, or if its even possible.  I have an async stomp client working, but I can't see how I would implement a sync version.

On the server side, my acceptor looks like this:

```
<acceptor name="stomp-acceptor">
  <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>        
  <param key="protocol" value="stomp" />
  <param key="port" value="61613" />
</acceptor>
```

and my listener looks like this:

```
public class SimpleSyncListener extends BaseListener implements SessionAwareMessageListener<Message> {

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
    String lastMessage = "";

    try {
        lastMessage = ((TextMessage) message).getText();

        //System.out.println("server recieved: " + lastMessage);

        Destination replyDestination = message.getJMSReplyTo();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("reply ");
        sb.append(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(lastMessage);
        TextMessage replyMessage = session.createTextMessage(sb.toString());
        replyMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSMessageID());

        MessageProducer replyProducer = session.createProducer(replyDestination);

        replyProducer.send(replyMessage);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    incrementCount();

}
```

I assume I need to put something in the temp queue and send it back like you do with JMS.  Its just not clear to me how that works with STOMP.  Do i need to open another tcp connection back on the client side that correspond to the "temp queue" on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stomp is a simple protocol, and on this case I don't think you can have a multiplexed channel. So you will probably need a Stream to send, and a Stream to receive.

Answer (score 0):

The common strategy to implement synchronous (request / response) communication with JMS - using temporary destinations - is also available with the STOMP implementations of many message brokers (ActiveMQ, Apollo, OpenMQ and RabbitMQ are examples).

However, HornetQ does not support temporary destinations in the current 2.4.0.Final version.